# Is it possible to catch some event after OnDrawCell? I would like to draw texts on a cells

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

[image: Stripes]

I would like to draw nice texts on a stripes after all drawing on TStringGrid is done.
Problem is I don't know when I can draw them. Is there any envent that occurs after OnDrawCell, when whole grid is drown?

Comment: `OnDrawCell` is responsible for drawing the entire cell. What is stopping you from using it to draw your text?

Comment: Now I'm thinking about how to draw each cell separately using OnDrawCell and texts in them, especially between two cells so they look not splitted. Maybe I should draw whole strip in memory and than copy cells-parts on a Grid's canvas.

Answer (score 1):

The `OnDrawCell` event is fired on the `TCustomDrawGrid.DrawCell` procedure (`VCL.Grids.pas`).
This method is `protected`, defined in `TCustomDrawGrid` class:

```
procedure DrawCell(ACol, ARow: Longint; ARect: TRect; AState: TGridDrawState); override;
```

You can `override` this method in your own class derived from `TStringGrid` and write whatever code you need after calling `inherited`.